# Creating HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an HTML form, using javascript, which has a standard drop down field & 3 text fields.

I need the ability to have the user choose the first drop down in order to display the rest of the form.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Before asking us, please do atleast a little bit of research on the subject. Try W3Schools.

Comment: I'd recommend [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML).

Comment: @AaronMiller Please see [meta.stackoverflow.com/...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource/87680#answer-87680). I do agree, there are better resources. However, not all information on _w3schools_ is invalid/inaccurate. In fact, if you get right down to it, I was on _w3fools_ not long ago and they had some discrepancies marked that _w3schools_ had corrected. So even _w3fools_ was out of date and inaccurate. I believe that the _MDN_ is a better resource. I just despise that _w3fools_ is being used any time _w3schools_ enters the conversation.

Answer (score 3):

Set the attribute "hidden" to the other ones while the first one isn't chosen, then remove the hidden state.